# Ubuntu dependency problems installing Synaptic

Tags: synaptic

I've recently replaced my WinXP with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32-bit), so I'm a total Linux newbie. I have installed TeXLive and now am trying to install TeXmaker.

I get dependency errors just like in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1919941, so I've subsequently tried to install `Synaptic` using a .deb file.

```
roy@roy-OEM:~$ sudo dpkg -i synaptic_0.81.1_i386.deb
[sudo] password for roy: 
Selecting previously unselected package synaptic.
(Reading database ... 138918 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking synaptic (from synaptic_0.81.1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of synaptic:
 synaptic depends on libapt-inst1.5 (>= 0.8.16~exp12); however:
  Package libapt-inst1.5 is not installed.
 synaptic depends on libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 0.9.11); however:
  Version of libapt-pkg4.12 on system is 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.16.
 synaptic depends on libept1.4.12; however:
  Package libept1.4.12 is not installed.
 synaptic depends on libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0); however:
  Package libpango-1.0-0 is not installed.
 synaptic depends on libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0); however:
  Package libpangocairo-1.0-0 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing synaptic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 synaptic
```

I'm using a .deb file from Softpedia (not a good idea?) because I haven't got an internet connection yet (I'll need to configure a dial up modem soon).

So - what exactly are these `lib*` packages on `ubuntu.com` and how can I install them correctly?

Comment: Why didn't you use `apt`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Like I said in my post, total Linux newbie.

Comment: if you dont have internet, linux is completely useless for a newbie considering how much google-ing is needed to understand even the simplest of tasks... a .deb doesnt contain the prereqs, just info on what they are. as i said... useless without internet.... furthermore dial up would do nothing short of drive me into a homicidal rage... @ElliottFrisch its probably not a portable box meaning the .deb must be DL'd using another PC and transferred using a usb or other medium

Comment: Normally, you would use `sudo apt-get install synaptic`. What is the result of `uname -m`? And, is this machine connected to your network?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This machine (Win7) is at my university. So I can't use Linux right now.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "I haven't got an internet connection yet (I'll need to configure a dial up modem soon)."

Comment: What is synaptic going to do for you without internet connectivity?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i believe he is attempting to solve a problem with another program, as directed in the provided link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.deb files do not contain the prerequisites... they only contain information on what those pre-requisites are (correct me if i am completely misinformed)... that would mean you need to install the prereqs separately if you dont have an active internet connection... typically a .deb would self install the needed prereqs but without internet it cant do that... in my opinion linux in any form is useless without an active internet connection (or an advanced understanding of how linux works/ what you will need to download before-hand)

as for how to install them... make a note of what the packages are called (write them down)... and attempt to find an installer for them...

you best option would be to bring your ubuntu box to the internet and re-run the .deb... it will auto-install the needed files... if you want to install them manually you can use the `apt-get` command like so

`sudo apt-get install (the package name you took note of)`

information on installing using `apt-get`:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

another option would be to simply bring the HD to the internet and boot from it on the university's PC... you might want a sata to usb adapter so you dont have to open the university’s computer and install the hard drive... you can typically boot a usb from the bios of your computer so you might even find that installing ubuntu directly to a usb stick is the best option for you...

long story short is this:

you need internet on your machine to learn how to use ubuntu (unless your have a patience of a turtle)

Comment: That sounds like a good plan. I'd vote up, but don't have enough rep.

Comment: @MedullaOblongata as for WHAT the lib packages are... lib stands for library... a library is a set of programs which are not (usually) directly runnable by the user... They are the foundation of how a program is coded... One might have a library for adding 2 numbers, or for drawing to the screen... they are typically useless alone, but are needed to make programs that utilise them work... related reading here--- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29

Answer (score 0):

You could simply install the missing libraries.

sudo apt-get install libapt-inst1.5 libept1.4.12

and so on then try to reinstall synaptic.

Comment: he doesnt have internet, so apt-get wont work for his purposes